# Can't set uid for operator Timestamps/Watermarks that doesn't exist

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on a project and have turned on the Flink option disableAutoGeneratedUIDs so as to make sure everything is given a proper uid. But I am getting an error when trying to run the job that says:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Auto generated UIDs have been disabled but no UID or hash has been assigned to operator Timestamps/Watermarks

Now I ran into the error for the operators I made when they didn't have uid set (as expected), but this operator isn't one I made or named. So I assumed it is the code for creating the WatermarkStrategy the source functions are using, but I can't give a WatermarkStrategy a uid so that was a dead end.

I looked online and saw there was a bug a year ago that said Partition required a uid when it shouldn't have and am wondering if this is a similar case (http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/How-to-assign-a-UID-to-a-KeyedStream-td32052.html).

What can I try next?

Comment: I have seen that error when missing to set `.uid(...)` on some operators. Are you completely sure you haven't missed any of your operators? IIRC some were not so obvious to identify, e.g. sources and/or sinks. If you set the logging level to `debug` you might be able to see what's the culprit operator. Also, if memory serves, in the UI dashboard you can see the names uids of the operators, that might give you some hints.

Comment: Have you used `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`, or is the source doing the watermarking? If the source, which source is this? Please share enough so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. I think it was just an overlook.

So the code originally was just:

```
getSource().name(NAME).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(getWatermarkStrategy())
            .process(new CountOperation())
            .name(COUNT_OPERATION_NAME);
```

In my first attempt I tried adding uid here:

```
getSource().name(NAME).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(getWatermarkStrategy())
            .uid("WatermarkUid")
            .process(new CountOperation())
            .name(COUNT_OPERATION_NAME);
```

Thinking that this would handle the whole "piece". Then when I first got errors saying "this count operation name doesn't have a uid" I moved the uid to after the .process:

```
getSource().name(NAME).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(getWatermarkStrategy())
            .process(new CountOperation())
            .uid("WatermarkUid")
            .name(COUNT_OPERATION_NAME);
```

Then that is when I saw the error saying operator Timestamps/Watermarks doesn't have a Uid. And I started looking for the operator named that in the code. But in my hazy "friday-brain" logic I somehow didn't figure out that the error was solved by the first uid because that is the default name for the assignTimestampsAndWatermarks (thank you @hourcos for the tip to look at the dashboard ui. Seeing the name in the operator block made everything click). So what solved it was just adding a uid like so:

```
getSource().name(NAME).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(getWatermarkStrategy())
            .uid("WatermarkUid")
            .process(new CountOperation())
            .uid("ToCountUid")
            .name(COUNT_OPERATION_NAME);
```